# IndexError: tuple index out of range - Sending the calculation of a mean to 4 processes in parallel

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I am trying to explore the topic of concurrency in python. I saw a couple of post about how to optimize processes by splitting the input data and processes separately, and afterwards joining the results. My task is to calculate the mean along the Z axis of a stack of rasters. I read the list of raster from a text file, and them create a stack numpy array with the data.

Then I wrote a simple function to use the stack array as input and calculate the mean. This task take me some minutes to complete. And I would like to process the numpy array in chunks to optimize the script. However when I do so by using the `numpy.split` (maybe a not good idea to split my 3d Array), then I get the following error:

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
File "C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\geoprocessing\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py",
line 553, in split
len(indices_or_sections)
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

During handling of the above exception, another exception ocurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tf_calculation_numpy.py", line 69, in <module>
main()
Tile "tf_calculation_numpy.py", line 60, in main
subarrays = np.split(final_array, 4)
File "C:\Users\~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\geoprocessing\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py", line 559, in split
array split does not result in an equal division'
ValueError: array split does not result in an equal division
```

Code is:

```
import rasterio
import os 
import numpy as np
import time
import concurrent.futures

def mean_py(array):
        print("Calculating mean of array")
        start_time = time.time()
        x = array.shape[1]
        y = array.shape[2]
        values = np.empty((x,y), type(array[0][0][0]))
        for i in range(x):
            for j in range(y):
                #no more need for append operations
                values[i][j] = ((np.mean(array[:, i, j])))

        end_time = time.time()
        hours, rem = divmod(end_time-start_time, 3600)
        minutes, seconds = divmod(rem, 60)
        print("{:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:05.2f}".format(int(hours),int(minutes),seconds))
        print(f"{'.'*80}")
        return values

def TF_mean(ndarray):
    sdir = r'G:\Mosaics\VH'
    final_array = np.asarray(ndarray)
    final_array = mean_py(final_array)
    out_name = (sdir + "/" + "MEAN_VH.tif")
    print(final_array.shape)

    with rasterio.open(out_name, "w", **profile) as dst:
            dst.write(final_array.astype('float32'), 1)
    print(out_name)
    print(f"\nDone!\n{'.'*80}")


def main():

    sdir = r'G:\Mosaics\VH'

    a = np.random.randn(250_000)
    b = np.random.randn(250_000)
    c = np.random.randn(250_000)
    e = np.random.randn(250_000)
    f = np.random.randn(250_000)
    g = np.random.randn(250_000)
    h = np.random.randn(250_000)
    arrays = [a, b, c, e, f, g, h]

    final_array = []
    for array in arrays: 
            final_array.append(array)
            print(f"{array} added")
    print("Splitting nd-array!")

    final_array = np.asarray(final_array)

    subarrays = np.split(final_array, 4)

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:

        for subarray, mean in zip(subarrays, executor.map(TF_mean,subarrays)):
            print(f'Processing {subarray}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I just expect to have four processes running in parallel and a way to obtained the 4 subarrays and write them as a whole Geotiff file.

Comment: Specifically, remove the extra code (hard-code the input; remove the output; reduce the array dimensions) and give us the *full* error message (includes trace-back).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second exception is the important one here, in terms of describing the error: `"array split does not result in an equal division"`

`final_array` is a 2D array, with `shape` 7 by 250,000. `numpy.split` operates along an axis, defaulting to axis 0, so you just asked it to split a length seven axis into four equal parts. Obviously, this isn't possible, so it gives up.

To fix, you can:

1. Split more; you could just split in seven parts and process each separately. The executor is perfectly happy to do seven tasks, no matter how many workers you have; seven won't split evenly, so at the tail end of processing you'll likely have some workers idle while the rest finish up, but that's not the end of the world
2. Split on a more fine-grained level. You could just flatten the array, e.g. `final_array = final_array.reshape(final_array.size)`, which would make it a flat 1,750,000 element array, which can be split into four parts.
3. Split unevenly; instead of `subarrays = np.split(final_array, 4)` which requires axis 0 to be evenly splittable, do `subarrays = np.split(final_array, (2,4,6))`, which splits into three groups of two rows, plus one group with a single row.

There are many other options depending on your use case (e.g. split on `axis=1` instead of the default `axis=0`), but those three are the least invasive (and #1 and #3 shouldn't change behavior meaningfully; #2 might, depending on whether the separation between 250K element blocks is meaningful).

Comment: Nice! It Works! And How do I merge de results of processing this subarrays into a final one?

Comment: @RogerAlmengor: I don't really understand the code logic (not a graphics guy), so I can't give specific guidelines there. If it's a purely aggregate function, presumably the (much smaller) returns can be further combined by the main process to the final result, but I don't have any specific guidelines to give you.

Comment: I changed the code, so It would be more clear what I want to accomplish.

Comment: I used the following: ```def mean_py(array):
    start_time = time.time() 
    x = array.shape[1]
    y = array.shape[2]
    values = np.empty((x,y), type(array[0][0][0]))
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            values[i][j] = ((np.mean(array[:,i,j))))
    end_time = time.time() 
    hours, rem = divmod(end_time-start_time, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(rem,60)
    print("{:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:05.2f}".format(int(hours, int(minutes), int(seconds)))
    print(f"{'.'*80}")
    return values ```

Comment: I used this formula to stack 4 arrays and return the stack: ```def generate_array():
    a = np.random.randn(250_000)
    a = np.random.randn(250_000)
    a = np.random.randn(250_000)
    a = np.random.randn(250_000)
    arrays = [a, b, c, d]
    final_array = []
    for array in arrays:
        final_array.append(array) 
        print(f"{array} added.")
    
    final_array = np.asarray(final_array)
    return final_array ```

Comment: And finally I split my array according to point 3 in your answer: ```with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:

    nd_array = generate_array() 
    print("Creating subarrays")
    subarrays = np.split(nd_array, (2,4,6))

    for subarray in subarrays:

         print(subarray)
         executor.map(mean_py, subarray) ```

Comment: The thing is: What happened after I apply executor.map(<formula>,*arg)`? I process the array, but when the result of the 4 different processes are merge into one, and I get the final array? Sorry I could not write the new code I Implemented on the question. I could not edit my code block in my question body anymore.